# Что отработает быстрее?

Tags: delphi

```
integer := integer + 1;
```

или

```
inc(integer);
```

Что отработает быстрее?

Comment: inc(integer);

 Ужас. А на C++ это просто integer++ или ++integer.

Comment: Смотри ниже правильный ответ! %)))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Абсолютно одинаково, оба оператора кодируются как `inc dword ptr [ebp-XX]`, то есть на машинном коде будет одна и та же операция.

Смотрим asm-код:

```
004520DF 33C0             xor eax,eax
004520E1 8945F8           mov [ebp-$08],eax
004520E4 33C0             xor eax,eax
004520E6 8945F4           mov [ebp-$0c],eax
004520E9 FF45F8           inc dword ptr [ebp-$08]
004520EC FF45F4           inc dword ptr [ebp-$0c]
```

Это код для:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
i,j: integer;
begin
i:=0;
j:=0;
inc(i);
j:= j+1;
showMessage(intToStr(i+j));
end;
```

Comment: Вообще-то, inc(integer) должно быть быстрее, просто в данном случае, может быть, компилятор оптимизировал выражение, но стоит ли на него надеяться постоянно? Кроме того, кто сказал, что при использовании другого компилятора все окажется точно так же? Так что лучше уж inc - ничего же не теряете))

Answer (score 1):

ну раз уж пошла такая пьянка, то inc использовать лучше, так как он в коде меньше места будет занимать, если переменные больше одного символа %)

```
inc(abc);
abc:=abc+1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Мне кажется, что `inc(integer);`

Comment: Когда кажется, надо ... ассемблерные листинги смотреть )

Comment: Смотри выше правильный ответ! ;)